# SQL Server why are all rows read when filter is indexed?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing

## Context

I'm working on optimizing my tables and specifically adding indexes to reduce reads/query. One of the tables identified as having high reads is the Users table. However the column being filtered on `ID` is already an index. Why is a simple query filtered by an index performing so many reads?

The table has about 200 rows. About half the time the query is run against it (according to SQL Server Profiler) it performs 112 reads requiring 16ms. I realize that none of these numbers are high per se but as this is a very common query and should be performing 1 read in >1ms I would love to know how to debug this further.

## Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ResetCode] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [ResetTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastLogin] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UserSettings] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Middle] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Address1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Address2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Inactive] [tinyint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

## Query

```
SELECT
    ID AS id,
    Name AS username,
    FirstName AS first_name,
    LastName AS last_name,
    Email AS email,
    Flag AS flag
FROM Users
WHERE ID = 180
```

## Execution Plan

This is from me manually executing it so not sure if it's the same as was used when sent from the php web app.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkCx99Xnf

Comment: Share your execution plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I'm not sure what an execution plan is but this is sql server 2008 so whatever it generates for me automatically.

Comment: Click the link I shared and click Instructions.

Comment: I didn't notice your index was clustered, so i deleted my comment. However, we still need the plan. Secondly, how fragmented is this index? If you drop and recreate the index (since there are so few rows) or just rebuild the index, you may see this change.

Comment: @scsimon - because the key being used is the primary key, the data is kept with the key, so once the kay is found then the data is in the same place and no further reads are required for that row. The execution plan is indeed required...

Comment: @dfundako Execution plan added.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it needs to read all the columns as you have no covering index that contains all the columns in your select statement.

You'd need to create an index that used the ID column and includes those columns you need.

Please note that not all versions of SQL server have covering indexes, 
the syntax is:

```
create index [IX_SingeUsers] on  [dbo].[Users] (ID)
include ([Name],[FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Flag])
```

adn yes, feel free to name the index differently than in my sample *IX_SingeUsers*

Alternatively, you can create a view with a covering index and select against that view. a view with an index is a "table" and stored and maintained as a table in SQL Server internals. you then only have the data you are looking for and is quite fast and best of all available in far more license models as covering indexes are.

A covered index is bound to a table schema, if you would like to update the table you'd first need to drop the view and then re-create it when you are done with your table changes.

The indexed views are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017), change the version to get the right information for the version you deploy to.

Update:
Please note that this isn't going to read all rows it is only going to read  those extents that fall in the index statistics (hope you update them) of the clustered index and the covering index mentioned, this is likely only 1 extend and only those columns that are in the index will likely fit in those 8 data pages as well. It doesn't need to go to the table as the index fetch will provide all the data the query needs to return.

Remember that SQL locking this data in the database that ensures no data is corrupted. if you have many users and no partitioning a table lock may occur. this will be a far greater impact on performance than the read from disk. Look at disk queue length to see if you have a problem with disk latency.

Comment: I'm confused what is the point of an identity index if it's going to read all the rows anyway? If a table has 2 Million rows and I want 5 columns from row id 1 million will it perform 1 million reads? I don't think this is correct unless I am actually filtering by those fields.

Comment: Hi Danielson, added the answer above